# Why is my CSS3 transition delaying before it starts?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Either I've misunderstood how it's working, or it simply isn't working. I have the following CSS:

```
transition-property: max-width;
transition-timing-function: linear;
transition-duration: 5s;
transition-delay: 0s;
```

What I expect is that when I click the button, the transitions starts and ends 5 seconds later.

What happens is that after I clicked the button, it delays for about 3,5 seconds before the transition starts and the transition lasts for about 1,5 seconds. So all in all, 5 seconds.

If I use `transition-timing-function: ease-in;` it delays for about 4,5 seconds before the transition starts.

I've been following [the transition guide here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

What can I do in order for the transition start the moment I click the button and then last for 5 seconds?

Comment: What are the start/end values of `max-width`? I have a hunch.

Comment: Doh! Good hunch! 80%......... that's probably it :)

Comment: The delay you are seeing is probably the time it takes to animate through values that don't result in a visual change, but I'd have to see more CSS to be 100% sure.

Comment: Yes it was. I totally forgot about that. Setting `max-width: 285px` instead of 80% fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delay you are seeing is probably the time it takes to animate through values that don't result in a visual change. Depending on the difference, it can cause a significant delay in the visual animation. This is why max/min width/height are often avoided when doing transitions.

Example of concept:

In the snippet below, the box has a height of 600px and a max-height of 1000px. In order for the animation to change the max-height to 200px, it has to go through 400px of empty space before you'll see a change. This is what causes the 'delay'.

```js
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.getElementById('box').className = 'box short';
});
```

```css
.box{
  margin:20px;
  width:200px;
  background:red;
  height:600px;
  max-height:1000px;
  transition: max-height 5s linear;
}

.box.short{
  max-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<button id="change">Change Max Height</button>

<div id="box" class="box"></div>
```